# Laptop won't stop restarting, never fully loads windows

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, reboot

I recently restarted my computer, and it loads to the 'starting windows' page, then shows a grey page, goes blank, and restarts. It has been continuing this process non-stop. I have tried loading it in safe mode, but it still does the same thing. I have tried most, if not all options on the page that appears when you tap the f8 key on start up and still no luck.

I have tried putting inserting the windows disk but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

I recently used the windows disk to install windows on another computer. I know you are only supposed to be allowed to install it on one computer. Would this be the cause of the problem? Or would I be dealing with something else like a virus?

Thanks,

Kimberley

Comment: See if you can boot to safe mode.

Comment: @DanielRHicks "I have tried loading it in safe mode, but it still does the same thing."

Comment: I missed that.  Apparently the hard drive is hosed.

Answer (score 3):

It does not sound like a virus to me. And if the safe boot is also not an option... I would recommend running some hard drive test tool, such as chkdsk either from Windows install CD command line or any other bootable rescue CD (such as Hiren's http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd). It might find and recover some lost files that stop you from booting. If it does not help, then I would recommend booting any live os and restoring to some of the Windows' recovery points, if that was enabled.

Comment: That's great thankyou. I can't however get to the command prompt, or windows to be able to run chkdsk. I can not get safe boot to work.i have also tried booting windows 7 home premium using the install disk but that does not help either.

Comment: I am not sure, but I believe there is an option to Repair installation instead of making brand new in the Windows boot CD, there are many options such as command prompt and system restore. If not then there is the sollution in Hiren's boot CD. You can boot Hiren and choose either some HD repair tool (but carefully, not to wipe your dis) or boot "Mini XP", which is a live system, that will allow you to perform chkdsk on any present drive and if that is not a solution, you may get back to some restore point.